# Koblitz's Method in Elliptic Curve Cryptography using Java

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am trying to convert a string to ECPoint using Koblitz's method.
The method stated that:
1. Say we have to send a character 'b'
2. 'b' is first encoded as number 11
3. Choose an auxiliary base parameter, for example `k=20`
4. For each number `mk`, take `x=mk+1` and try to solve for `y`
5. If you can't do it, then try `x=mk+2` and then `x=mk+3` until you can solve for `y`
6. Now the point `(x,y)` is encrypted and decrypted as a message.

I can't understand steps number 4 to 5. Can anyone help explain it to me?

**Answer:**
I've figured out how to solve for `y`. Use shanks-tonelli algorithm to do it.